# SymmetricDS - How to prevent configuration pull during store node registration

Tags: file, configuration, synchronization, beanshell, symmetricds

I am having same file triggers configured differently in corp and store node (different source base_dir for each store), but now the file triggers /all configurations are syncing to a store node immediately after its registration.

I have given the following properties in corp node and store node properties file.

```
  auto.sync.configuration=false
  auto.sync.triggers=false
```

It prevented the configuration and trigger syncing after the start-up, but still the sync occurs immediately after the store node registration.

Any help to move forward is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FILE_TRIGGER_ROUTERs should be linked to proper ROUTERs which would then define the source and destination node. This means that there wouldn't need to be a manual configuration of different FILE_TRIGGERs on the corp and store nodes. All configuration has to be central, so it can be pushed from the corp and executed correctly from all nodes (including store nodes).